# 'itkSingleValuedCostFunction.h': No such file or directory

Tags: itk

I am trying to calculate the mutual information between two images, for that purpose I am using the class ‘MutualInformationImageToImageMetric’. After reading this example : http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/Registration/MutualInformation I am using the following new four  ‘#include’ lines in my code:

```
 #include "itkImageRegistrationMethod.h"
 #include "itkTranslationTransform.h"
 #include "itkMutualInformationImageToImageMetric.h"
 #include "itkLinearInterpolateImageFunction.h"
```

After that I received a fatal error telling me that : 'itkSingleValuedCostFunction.h': No such file or directory

I have use quite a lot of other classes of itk and it works always…what is happening now? Any hints please?

Thanks !

Antonio Gómez Barquero

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the GIT version of ITK and updated my CMakeList.txt to

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(MutualInformation)

FIND_PACKAGE(ITK REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${ITK_USE_FILE})

ADD_EXECUTABLE(MutualInformation MutualInformation.cxx)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MutualInformation ${ITK_LIBRARIES})
```

Everything went fine.

Which ITK have you built?
I do not have ITK 3.20 built right now. Does itkSingleValuedCostFunction.h exist under Code\Numerics ? Is you makefile properly set to TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MutualInformation ITKIO ITKNumerics) ?
Or, if you use ITK git, do you see the file under Modules\Numerics\Optimizers\include ?

Note that you could post questions related to ITK on the ITK mailing list. Register at http://www.itk.org/mailman/listinfo/insight-users

Comment: Thanks for reply! I am using Windows 7,not Linux. And about CMakeList.txt I did not change anything, just I built it with the Cmake 2.6 version and the GUI. And yes, itkSingleValuedCostFunction.h do exist under Code\Numerics and also some more headers that I need are under Code/SpatialObject ... what should I do? remake the cmake building? that will make my programs not to work? thanks!